# How to load and use quicklisp program

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp

I've set up quicklisp (with latest SBCL) and done

```
* (ql:quickload "draw-cons-tree")
```

and I get the reply

```
To load "draw-cons-tree":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    draw-cons-tree
; Loading "draw-cons-tree"

("draw-cons-tree")
```

I check my `quicklisp` directory and I see it's been downloaded, essentially exactly [these](https://github.com/cbaggers/draw-cons-tree) contents. So how do I actually use `draw-cons-tree` in the SBCL REPL that I have opened? The github sites says:

```
* (draw-tree '(a b (c nil 1)))
```

should produce

```
[o|o]---[o|o]---[o|/]
 |       |       |      
 A       B      [o|o]---[o|o]---[o|/]
                 |       |       |      
                 C      NIL      1      
NIL
```

but I'm just getting

```
debugger invoked on a UNDEFINED-FUNCTION in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10005385B3}>:
  The function COMMON-LISP-USER::DRAW-TREE is undefined.
```

What am I missing here? My only other real experience with quicklisp has been slime, which had a specific `.el` file to call in Emacs to get slime going. Do I need to drill down into the directory

```
~/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/draw-cons-tree-20131003-git/draw-cons-tree.lisp
```

and load the beast each time I want to use it? I tried that and, strangely for me at least, I get a list of WARNINGs of redefined functions, one is `draw-tree`. So my REPL knows about `draw-tree` but doesn't? What am I missing here?

Comment: The system `draw-cons-tree` defines a package named `DRAW-CONS-TREE`, which exports a function named `DRAW-TREE`. To call the function, you must either use the package qualified name for it, ie. `(draw-cons-tree:draw-tree ...)`, or import the function name into the current package (eg. by using `(use-package :draw-cons-tree)`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quicklisp loads a system, which may add zero, one or more packages to your environment. Sometimes the names of those packages are easy to guess, like when you install system `cl-ppcre`, you have a package named `"CL-PPCRE"` from which you can run things. Sometimes you must read the documentation to know how to use a system you installed.

But in case you are looking for a specific function, then you can use `apropos`:

```
CL-USER> (apropos "draw-tree")
DRAW-CONS-TREE::%DRAW-TREE
DRAW-CONS-TREE:DRAW-TREE (fbound)
:DRAW-TREE (bound)
```

Here, there is one exported symbol, either call it with its name fully qualified:

```
(DRAW-CONS-TREE:DRAW-TREE ...)
```

Or use the package first, so that the symbol is accessible from the current package:

```
> (use-package "DRAW-CONS-TREE")
> (draw-tree ...)
```

Alternatively, define a new package that uses the package, or go in that package with `in-package` to have access to its symbols, etc.

See [Programming in the Large: Packages and Symbols](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html).

Comment: I will read the Seibel chapter. However, I killed my sbcl repl, restarted -- but had to do another `(ql:quickload "draw-cons-tree")` to get `draw-cons-tree` back. Interesting. I thought `(ql:quickload "draw-cons-tree")` installed it and made any subsequent repl find it. I guess I'm used to Emacs doing a `(require 'xyz)` JIT behind the scenes.

Comment: @147pm quickload fetches the system under the quicklisp/ directory (so that subsequent quickload don't fetch it again), then loads the system *in the current environment*" (restarting Sbcl, like restarting Emacs, clears the runtime state). Emacs has a special "autoload" feature that make "require" now what file to load; Modules, a.k.a. the require/provide approach that also exists in CL is not recommended anymore; ASDF is a better replacement (quicklisp relies on ASDF). Typically you just describe your own ASDF system "foo", notably its dependencies, and just call (ql:quickload "foo").